# Magnetic constant in vacuum: different values in the Italian textbooks for high school

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

My simple question is that in different Italian textbooks I have seen that the magnetic constant in vacuum $k_m$ is defined as:

$$k_m=\frac{\mu_0}{2\pi} \tag 1$$

Below there is a screenshot of my digital book written also with `MathJaX` where there is the name of the [book](https://www.mondadorieducation.it/catalogo/le-risposte-della-fisica-0054107/).

[image]

After from the [book](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pearson.it%2Fopera%2Flinx_edizioni%2F0-6177-fisica_modelli_teorici_e_problem_solving&psig=AOvVaw0rS_9k3lNZ6qxHC1hMMPaR&ust=1587118763886000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMCF8qrc7OgCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE), Walker in Italian language:

[image]
[image]

While in my university notes I have

$$k_m=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \tag 2$$

Surely the correct value is the $(2)$. Any observation or comment is welcome.

Comment: Does it really matter? All it's going to change is whether or not you have a factor of $2$ in front of your $k_m$ which is completely meaningless.

Comment: @ArthurMorris For me it was important  the classic Physics tradition and not if there is a factor 2 or no.

Comment: People who write high school textbooks often don't know anything about physics, and textbook writers within a country tend to copy each other. So it is very common that all the high school textbooks in a country will all agree on something, but they'll all be wrong.

Comment: @knzhou My question are simple but unfortunately, even my Italian colleagues don't see these things. I make my criticisms but they are disinterested. I approve of your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern usage is that “magnetic constant” [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability#Terminology) $\mu_0$ (with no $2\pi$ or $4\pi$) and “electric constant” [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity#Terminology) $\epsilon_0$ (with no $4\pi$).

It is common to call $k_e=1/4\pi\epsilon_0$ the [Coulomb constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_constant). Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law) $k_A=\mu_0/4\pi$ but does not call it the Ampere constant, although the notation suggests this.

I have never seen anyone give $\mu_0/2\pi$ a symbol such as $k_m$, and doing so strikes me as bizarre given that $\epsilon_0\mu_0=k_A/k_e=1/c^2$. Using $k_m=\mu_0/2\pi$ instead of $k_A=\mu_0/4\pi$ would get rid of the 2 in [Ampere’s force law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_force_law), but at the cost of introducing a factor of 2 into the more fundamental relation between electricity and magnetism in the previous sentence.

The theorists I have worked with have always used Gaussian units (and also $c=1$) where there are *none* of these constants to worry about! As far as I am concerned, SI units are for experimentalists and engineers and do nothing but *obscure* electromagnetism. This is especially the case when teachers still use obsolete terms like “vacuum permittivity” for $\epsilon_0$ and “vacuum permeability” for $\mu_0$, which suggest — wrongly — that there is something *physical* about these constants.